# Can you any body help me about tcp_sk and udp_sk this type of functions?

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel

I explored above functions inside linux stack, what am understanding they done inside function   type casting but my doubt is they type casting is more bytes to less bytes . how should it work and how to store values after type casting. Please how it works that means struct sock is big structure compare to others .But still its type casting. Can you please any body help me above issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct tcp_sock {
    /* inet_connection_sock has to be the first member of tcp_sock */
    struct inet_connection_sock     inet_conn;
```

...

```
struct inet_connection_sock {
    /* inet_sock has to be the first member! */
    struct inet_sock          icsk_inet;
```

...

```
struct inet_sock {
    /* sk and pinet6 has to be the first two members of inet_sock */
    struct sock             sk;
```

...